# Parse object with nested object parsing- Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, parse-platform

Thanks for looking into my question. I have two parse classes Game and CricketScore. Game has "first_inning_score" and "second_inning_score" pointers to CricketScore class.

I am only getting pointers to CricketScore as shown below. **How can I get actual data from CricketScore?(RESOLVED). Now question is how to show data in handlebar??**

I am getting this JSON Object from parse(**updated**)

```
   {
    "results": [
        {
            "first_inning_score": {
                "overs": "0",
                "parent": {
                    "__type": "Pointer",
                    "className": "Game",
                    "objectId": "Yibf5wHLIM"
                },
                "team_name": "Fr11",
                "wickets": "0",
                "innings": "1",
                "runs": "0",
                "createdAt": "2014-09-30T18:27:36.640Z",
                "updatedAt": "2014-09-30T18:27:36.640Z",
                "objectId": "0NhGUYySg5",
                "__type": "Object",
                "className": "CricketScore"
            },
            "second_inning_score": {
                "wickets": "0",
                "innings": "2",
                "runs": "0",
                "team_name": "Rb11",
                "overs": "0",
                "parent": {
                    "__type": "Pointer",
                    "className": "Game",
                    "objectId": "Yibf5wHLIM"
                },
                "createdAt": "2014-09-30T18:27:36.760Z",
                "updatedAt": "2014-09-30T18:27:36.760Z",
                "objectId": "4gHyHO84Ep",
                "__type": "Object",
                "className": "CricketScore"
            },
            "city": "Poway",
            "elected": "bowl",
            "groundname": "4s RANCH",
            "hometeam": "Rb11",
            "maxovers": "20",
            "score_moderator": [
                {
                    "__type": "Pointer",
                    "className": "_User",
                    "objectId": "00hBJbvgmu"
                }
            ],
            "sport": "Cricket",
            "status": "inning1",
            "team1": "Fr11",
            "team2": "Rb11",
            "toss": "Rb11",
            "createdAt": "2014-09-30T18:27:36.504Z",
            "updatedAt": "2014-09-30T18:27:36.898Z",
            "objectId": "Yibf5wHLIM"
        }
    ]
}
```

Handlebar code

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="single-quote-template">
    <!-- Feed Entry -->
    <div class="row singleQuote">
      <div class="panel" align="center">
        <p><h4><strong>         {{team1}}  vs {{team2}}</strong></h4></p>
        <p>Toss won by {{toss}} elected to {{elected}}, {{createdAt}}, {{groundname}}</p>
        <p>{{first_inning_score.wickets}}</p>  // ** <<---this is not working****

      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </script>
```

Javascript code. I dont know how to get cricketscores yet. I am unable to follow Dehli's answer below.

```
 query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      // The query was successful, and has passed
      // back an array of PFObjects for you to use

      // Since we're appending, clear the list out 
      // every time we're about to add results
      $("#quoteList").html("");

      // Compile the Handlebars template we're going
      // to stick the results into. Pass Handlebars the
      // ID of the script tags in index.html that contain
      // the template.
      var template = Handlebars.compile($("#single-quote-template").html());

      // Iterate over all the results
      $(results).each(function(i,e) {
        // Serialize the PFObject and store it in q
         var q = e.toJSON();
        // Select the DOM element we're appending to,
        // Then append the template, passing in q to
        // provide the values of the template variables
        $("#quoteList").append(template(q));
      });
    },
    error: function(error) {
      if (error.message == "unauthorized") {
        // Temporary message if you haven't added your own credentials for Parse.com yet. Remove once set up.
        console.warn("Please fill in your own Parse.com App ID and Javascript Key on line 107 of index.html");
      }
      // Handle the error here
    }
  })
```

Comment: What's your query look like? Try adding `query.include("first_inning_score");` and `query.include("second_inning_score");`

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! This has worked. Can you please show me how can I put data from first inning score to handle bar? See updated code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is add the following to your JavaScript query.

```
query.include("first_inning_score");
query.include("second_inning_score");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you response. Can you please explain " Then to extract out the score, parse out each of the scores and look at the appropriate keys". I am newbie.

Comment: Hi Dehli, thanks a lot for taking time. I am unable to understand where to put your code in my code. I have pasted my JS query for Parse. I am getting results Json object from parse. I am able to access first level data such as createdAt, team1, team2 etc. But not first_inning_score. Eventual aim it to show data in handlebar in my html file.. Can you please tell me how to loop through the JSON?

Comment: Can you replace wickets with this: `first_inning_score.length`

Comment: I replace it in HTML and nothing happened.

Comment: Does having just: `first_inning_score` show anything?

Comment: Joined by the name of parse_issue